# Multiple Classes not working in Responsive Email HTML

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, html-email

I have a responsive HTML email I am working on.  All my code is inlined with the exception of media queries.  (I know this will not work on some email clients!)  Within the media queries I have 2 classes defined:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), screen and (max-width: 550px) {

img[class="width320"] { 
width: 320px !important;
}

img[class="autoHeight"] {
height:auto !important;
}
}
```

When I add them to the HTML -

```
<tr>
    <td width="700" class="" style="display: block;" border="0">
        <img src="Welcome_WoodBottom.jpg" class="width320 autoHeight" height="26" width="700" border="0" alt="" style="display:block;" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

both styles do not work.  The styles work individually, but not when they are together.  When I inspect the code in Firebug, the classes "width320" and "autoHeight" do not even show up in the inspector.

What am I missing?  Can you not use multiple classes in email media queries for some reason?

I would really like to use multiple classes in a variety of areas in my emails, so I am hoping for a solution.  Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Try this img.width320{} and img.autoHeight{} instead of img[class="autoHeight"]{}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select an element on css by the attribute selector (`[attribute="value"]`), it looks for the exactly value specified on the tag. In your case, your img "style" attribute value is `"width320 autoHeight"`. So, `img[class="width320 autoHeight"]` would work, because you are searching for the exactly value.

Since you want to check if the element contains a certain class, the right way to do so on the css selector is using the `.class` syntax. So it would be like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), screen and (max-width: 550px) {

    img.width320 { 
        width: 320px !important;
    }

    img.autoHeight {
        height:auto !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense.  Since this is email, I need to select the element by the attribute selector, but I want to keep the classes separate so I can add other classes to that style.  Is there a way to do this with the .class syntax and still make it work for email?

Comment: You can use the class as an attribute name. Like: `<img src="Welcome_WoodBottom.jpg" width320="" autoHeight=""`. Then you can select it by the attribute selector: `img[width320]` and `img[autoHeight]`

Comment: Interesting!  Do you know if that is safe for all email clients?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following format:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px), screen and (max-width: 550px) {

img[class].width320 { 
    width: 320px !important;
}

img[class].autoHeight {
    height:auto !important;
} }
```

This will then allow you to apply the two classes to the image.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this recently with the CSS [attribute~=value] Selector:

```
* [class~="fullWidth"] {
width:100% !important;
max-width:100% !important;
}
* [class~="autoHeight"] {
height: auto !important;
}

<td class="fullWidth autoHeight">...</td>
```

And this seems to render well accross mobile email clients. Could you try this?

Comment: This doesn't work at all for me